# How to let a textfield hover/float above a mapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I'm making an app which uses MapView, now I've positioned the textfield above the mapview, like on the image.[image] But I really want to fullscreen the mapview and let a textfield float/hover above it. Does anybody know how I can make something like that? I have searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find any clue.. Hope someone can get me starting.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: if you mean using constraints, yes. But how could I get it flying over the mapview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, presumably your map view is pinned on all four sides to its superview? Setup your constraints as follows, not how the mapview is not pinned to the text field, but the superview.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g407U.jpg

To add the drop shadow, set the following properties on your UITextField:

```
textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
textField.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
textField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, -1.0)
```

Adjust the settings until you are happy with the look of the shadow.

To dismiss the keyboard when the user pans around the map is very simple. You just need to implement the delegate. Edit your class to look a bit like this:

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.delegate = self
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and a cool vido! But I think I haven't described my question clear enough. I want to make something like this: http://imgur.com/a/o2IhT So I've got an textfield thats floating/above the mapview. Couldn't find any information 'bout it..

Comment: So what is it you're looking for specifically? Using the constraint setup from my clip you can have the text field on top of the map, is is specifically the shadow that you want to give that floating impression?

Comment: Well, I've managed to get it above the mapView now, some shadow would be really nice, but only if possible

Comment: How awesome thanks! 1 little question: I managed to dismiss a keyboard when typing in a textfield, but in the mapview it looks impossible to catch the user his tap with the UITapGestureRecognizer. At my register page it's working but not on the mapview.. any idea?

Comment: Let my get this straight, you want to dismiss the keyboard when the user taps or pans around the map?

Comment: Yes that's right, the whole page is mapview, so a tap around the map would be nice to dismiss the keyboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124808/discussion-between-royvano-and-jacob-king).

Comment: I'm thankfull for your reply, but this solution is not removing my keyboard.. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, can I send you a message through the chat?